# React - render after single item modification in array

Tags: reactjs

My problem goes like this:
I'm rendering an array of items using "map".
Each rendered item also includes a toggle button component that i created. You can refer this as regular checkbox.
The checkbox value will decided if the rendered item will have a specific css class, with transitions.

Here come's the problem.
On state change, i update the whole list. Therefore, the whole list is being re-rendered. Therefore, i get the relevant item with the relevant boolean value. Despite that, this item isn't modified, it's re-rendered, so the css doesn't change from A to B, it's just getting a new css class instead the previous, so the TRANSITION DOESN'T WORK.

The rendered array:

```
            {this.state.extensions.map((curr,index)=>{
            return <div className="single-extension" key={'extension-' + Utils.guid()}>
                <div className="toggle-area">
                    <ToggleButton onChange={(value)=>{
                        this.handleAssociateExtension(index,value);
                    }} active={curr.associated}/>
                </div>
                <div className={ClassNames({'details':true, 'on': curr.associated})}>
                    <div className="link-text">{curr.link_text}</div>
                    <div className="description">{curr.description}</div>
                    <div className="landing-page">{curr.landing_page}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        })}
```

The update function:

```
    handleAssociateExtension(index, value) {
    let extensions = Utils.cloneObject(this.state.extensions);
    if (extensions[index]) {
        extensions[index].associated = value;
    }
    this.setState({extensions: extensions});
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: if `key={'extension-' + Utils.guid()}` creates a new key every render I would try to strictly associate every item with some kind of id so `key` wouldn't change on subsequent rerenders and see how it goes

Comment: What is the output of your `ClassNames()` function? Seems like that could be the culprit.

Comment: @berrtech, your'e great. Didn't think about it. It works. Bless you!